# How to sort structured blocks?

Tags: sorting

There are cases where I wish to sort data that has been wrapped across multiple lines, making a simple line-sort not work usefully e.g.

```elisp
'("x" "b" "c" "a lot of text")
'("a" "y" "z" "a lot of text")
```

This sorts into:

```elisp
'("a" "y" "z" "a lot of text")
'("x" "b" "c" "a lot of text")
```

---

However I would like the same outcome if the lines are wrapped. e.g.

```elisp
'("a" "y" "z"
  "a lot of text")
'("x" "b" "c"
  "a lot of text")
```

---

Is there a way to sort structured text that respects structure?

Comment: It seems to me that your problem here is that you have undelimited Lisp data, or that you are using text delimiters (line ends) instead of Lisp delimiters (parentheses). Can you perhaps expound a little on why you (think you) need to do this? What would not work if your listed sexps were themselves enclosed (without their respective leading quote marks) in a single list? That is, `'(("x" "b" ...) ("a" "y" ...))`?

Comment: The lisp is just an example - it could be C++ or Python. Too (the actual case I ran into was Python). Another way to look at this is - I want to sort lines - as if the auto-formatter had nor wrapped them). I could of course auto-format them to be longer, sort, then auto-format back, but in practice that's quite inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

See the various sort commands, such as `sort-pages`, `sort-paragraphs`, and `sort-regexp-fields`.

The first two require the things you want to sort to be what Emacs recognizes as pages and paragraphs, respectively. E.g., pages are separated by `C-l` characters.

The third one lets you define the things to sort by the text that matches a regexp you supply. It sounds like that one will work for your use case, which seems to be sorting lists (matching corresponding `(` and `)` chars).

See the Elisp manual, node [Sorting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sorting.html).

`C-h f` sort-regexp-fields`:

> **`sort-regexp-fields`** is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
> `sort.el`.
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar edit sort sort-regexp-fields`.
>
> `(sort-regexp-fields REVERSE RECORD-REGEXP KEY-REGEXP BEG END)`
>
> Sort the text in the region lexicographically.
>
> If called interactively, prompt for two regular expressions,
> `RECORD-REGEXP` and `KEY-REGEXP`.
>
> `RECORD-REGEXP` specifies the textual units to be sorted.
> For example, to sort lines, `RECORD-REGEXP` would be `"^.*$"`.
>
> `KEY-REGEXP` specifies the part of each record (i.e. each match for
> `RECORD-REGEXP`to be used for sorting.
> If it is `"\\digit"`, use the digit'th `"\\(...\\)"`
> match field specified by `RECORD-REGEXP`.
> If it is `"\\&"`, use the whole record.
> Otherwise, `KEY-REGEXP` should be a regular expression with which
> to search within the record.  If a match for `KEY-REGEXP` is not
> found within a record, that record is ignored.
>
> With a negative prefix arg, sort in reverse order.
>
> The variable `sort-fold-case` determines whether alphabetic case affects
> the sort order.
>
> For example: to sort lines in the region by the first word on each line starting with the letter "f",
> `RECORD-REGEXP` would be `"^.*$"` and `KEY` would be `"\\<f\\w*\\>"`

Answer (score 1):

The description of your question suggests that your structured blocks are actually sexps which contain sexps.
You can easily employ the driver function `sort-subr` for sorting those.

One has to provide a number of functions as arguments of `sort-subr`:
We use

- `(comment-forward most-positive-fixnum)` to go to the beginning of the next sexpr
- a function `sort-sexps-end` to go from the middle of a top-level sexpr to its end
- a function `sort-sexps-goto-subexpr` to go from the start of the sexpr to the start of the inner sexps that serves as sorting key
- `forward-sexp` to go to the end of the sorting key

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(defun sort-sexps-end ()
  "Skip to the end of the top level sexp."
  (interactive)
  (let ((state (parse-partial-sexp (point-min) (point))))
    (parse-partial-sexp (point) (point-max) 0 nil state)
    ))

(defun sort-sexps-goto-subexpr (n)
  "Enter the list at point and go to subexpression N."
  (down-list)
  (forward-sexp n)
  (comment-forward most-positive-fixnum))

(defun sort-sexps (reverse beg end &optional subexpr)
  "Sort sexps in region at top level with sorting key SUBEXPR.
SUBEXPR is the index of the subexpression of the sort-key.
Called from a program, there are three arguments:
REVERSE (non-nil means reverse order), BEG and END (region to sort).
The variable `sort-fold-case' determines whether alphabetic case affects
the sort order."
  (interactive "P\nr\nnIndex of key subexpression (starting at 0): ")
  (unless subexpr (setq subexpr 0))
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region beg end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
    (sort-subr reverse
           (lambda () (comment-forward most-positive-fixnum))
           #'sort-sexps-end
           (lambda () (sort-sexps-goto-subexpr subexpr))
           #'forward-sexp
           ))))
```